# redirecting to another page in html

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to redirect html form page after submission of data to an another html page  using meta req method. Is their any other method ro redirect page as the problem with this is that it shows an intermediate page of our php command which i dont want 
my html code is

```
    <form method="POST" action="yoga_signup.php">
            <div class="row" style="    margin-top:4rem; margin-left:24rem;">
                <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto p-0">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="login-box">
                            <div class="login-snip"> <input id="tab-1" type="radio" name="tab" class="sign-in" checked><label for="tab-1" class="tab">Login</label> <input id="tab-2" type="radio" name="tab" class="sign-up"><label for="tab-2" class="tab">Sign Up</label>
                                <div class="login-space">
                                    <div class="login">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="for_page" value="login">
                                        <div class="group"> <label for="user" class="label">Username</label> <input id="user" type="text" class="input" name="username" placeholder="Enter your username" required> </div>
                                        <div class="group"> <label for="pass" class="label">Password</label> <input id="pass" type="password" name="password_1" class="input" data-type="password" placeholder="Enter your password" required> </div>
                                        <div class="group"> <input id="check" type="checkbox" class="check" checked> <label for="check"><span class="icon"></span> Keep me Signed in</label> </div>
                                        <div class="group"> <input type="submit" class="button" value="Sign In"> </div>
                                        <div class="hr"></div>
```

my php code for the same is

```
<?php

session_start();
$conn= new mysqli("localhost","root","","yoga");

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
    $TypeOfRequest=$_POST['for_page'];
    if($TypeOfRequest=="signup"){
        $user=$_POST['username'];
        $pass_1=$_POST['password_1'];
        $pass_2=$_POST['password_2'];
        $mail=$_POST['email'];

    if($pass_1===$pass_2){
        $val=" INSERT INTO yoga_login(username,password_1,password_2,email) VALUES('$user','$pass_1','$pass_2','$mail')";
        if($conn->query($val)===TRUE){
            echo "redirecting to login page.<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;login.html'>";
        }else{

            echo "registration unsucessfull";

        }


        }
    if($pass_1!==$pass_2){
        echo "please enter the same password";
    }
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
```

so is their any other method which doesnt shows the intermediate page like this

[image: intermediate page image]

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php `Location: login.html`

Comment: can u plz carify the format of writing it as im finding little difficulty because i want to redirect only after submitting form

Comment: Replace the `meta` tag with `header('Location: login.html');`

Comment: thnx it is working correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace:

```
echo "redirecting to login page.<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;login.html'>";
```

With the PHP redirect:

```
header('Location: login.html');
exit;  // this is normally a good idea
```